# Upload multiple images to a folder with each input having a different name

Tags: php, html

I am trying to upload multiple images to a folder using PHP using this tutorial I managed:

In the PHP form

```
<?php
  $success = 0;
  $fail = 0;
  $uploaddir = 'uploads/';
  for ($i=0;$i<4;$i++)
  {
   if($_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i])
   {
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i]);
    $ext = strtolower(substr($uploadfile,strlen($uploadfile)-3,3));
    if (preg_match("/(jpg|gif|png|bmp)/",$ext))
    {
     if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i], $uploadfile)) 
     {
      $success++;
     } 
     else 
     {
     echo "Error Uploading the file. Retry after sometime.\n";
     $fail++;
     }
    }
    else
    {
     $fail++;
    }
   }
  }
  echo "<br> Number of files Uploaded:".$success;
  echo "<br> Number of files Failed:".$fail;
?>
```

In the HTML form

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="post">
Image1: <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
Image2: <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
Image3: <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
Image4: <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

As you can see in the HTML form the input name is userfile[] for all of them. Now in my HTML for the input names are as follows: picture01, picture02, picture 03, etc...

How can I modify the **PHP code** to have my input names {: picture01, picture02, picture 03} rather than userfile[].

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I want the above to fit in my HTML Form

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="post">
    Picture 01<input id="picture01"  name="picture01" type="file" ><br />
    Picture 02<input id="picture02"  name="picture02" type="file" ><br />
   Picture 03<input id="picture03"  name="picture03" type="file" ><br />
    Picture 04<input id="picture04"  name="picture04" type="file" ><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>
```

Comment: About 90% sure you can set `$uploadFile = $uploadDir. "picture".$i;`

Comment: Mine are two digit say Picture01 - can you please update the code?

Comment: Check out [str_pad](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php).

Comment: i didn't manage. Can you please change it to show me two digit please?

Comment: `$uploadFile=$uploadDir."picture".str_pad($i,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);`

Comment: what about the other lines in my php code like ` if($_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i])` and ` if 1(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i], $uploadfile))

Comment: What about them? :) Did the new $uploadFile value not work? Any errors?

Comment: I changed that line and it takes me to my 404 error page :-( The other lines I told  you contain _userfile_ in both in the orginal PHP

Comment: Give me a moment. I will try it locally and report back.

Comment: Any luck my good friend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is working locally. It uses a combination of your code and the example from php.net. You should probably use [pathinfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) to get the extension but that's a minor detail.

form.html

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="post">
Image1: <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
Image2: <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
Image3: <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
Image4: <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

upload.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors",1);
$success = 0;
$fail = 0;

$uploads_dir = 'uploads';
$count = 1;
foreach ($_FILES["userfile"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["userfile"]["name"][$key];
        $uploadfile = "$uploads_dir/$name";
        $ext = strtolower(substr($uploadfile,strlen($uploadfile)-3,3));
        if (preg_match("/(jpg|gif|png|bmp)/",$ext)){
            $newfile = "$uploads_dir/picture".str_pad($count++,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).".".$ext;
            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $newfile)){
                $success++;
            }else{
                echo "Couldn't move file: Error Uploading the file. Retry after sometime.\n";
                $fail++;
            }
        }else{
            echo "Invalid Extension.\n";
            $fail++;
        }
    }
}
echo "<br> Number of files Uploaded:".$success;
echo "<br> Number of files Failed:".$fail;
```

Comment: In my case the html code is as follows e.g. for picture 1 **Picture 01<input id="picture01"  name="picture01" type="file" >** and for picture 2 **Picture 02<input id="picture02"  name="picture02" type="file" >** your php code still contains _userfile_ from the original php code.

Comment: userfile is based on the input name from your html form above. It will name them picture01, etc. after the upload during the move from temp to your upload directory.

Comment: can you update it re my HTML please? I would like them to be say _picture02_ instead of _userfile_ in the HTML form.

Comment: What is the error in the php log file? You need to set the temporary directory in php.ini if you haven't yet. Restart the server afterwards. Make sure the temporary directory and upload directory have appropriate permissions.

Comment: The HTML was better before!

Comment: The error is when the page is loaded _Number of files Uploaded:0
Number of files Failed:0_ The files are not uploading. I think the problem lies in the fact that the _"userfile"_ in the original file is still present in your php code

Comment: You *need* userfile[] as your field names if you want to loop through all the uploaded files. Also add the following at the top of your PHP file: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors",1);`

Comment: Thanks. Thanks to your help I realised what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When you have change the names in the form, change the name when you try to get an array element of the file

ex.

```
echo $_FILES["picture$i"]['name'];
```

and change the for as this

```
for ($i=1;$i<=4;$i++)
```

Comment: It's for get the picture names on numeric order which go from one to four